# benefits of using CF variables over NS ones

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I noticed that there are variables and functions used by many libraries that start with `CF` and ends with `Ref`, like: `CFStringRef` , `CFURLRef` , `CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest` , etc ...

1) what does `CF` stand for ? I don't know why apple does not say a word about such abbreviations.

2) what's the benefit(s) of using (for ex.) `CFStringRef` instead of using `NSString` ?

3) if it's better to use these `CF` variables, should I then replace all regular variable like `NSString` with `CFStringRef` ?

Comment: CF == Core Foundation, NS == NextStep. CF is a `C` API. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Foundation

Comment: I'm not sure, but I can tell you NS stands for Next Step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CF` stands for Core Foundation. If you're interested in learning more about that, you can start by reading the [Core Foundation Design Concepts Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i). There are also the [String Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/introCFStrings.html) and [Collections Programming Topics for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/CFCollections.html), which will tell you more about `CFStringRef` and the various collection types (arrays, dictionaries, and so forth).

Basically, Core Foundation is a relatively low-level framework that does some of the same things that Foundation does, but is written in C, and not Objective-C. Some Core Foundation "classes" (they're not really classes) are also "toll-free bridged" with their Objective-C counterparts, for example, it is possible to cast a `CFStringRef` to an `NSString *` (though it is a little more complicated with ARC).

If you don't need specific APIs that are only available in Core Foundation, there's absolutely no need to use it instead of Foundation. Core Foundation code tends to be less readable than Objective-C and also makes memory management a bit more complicated.

However, it can be quite useful to familiarize oneself with the basic concepts of Core Foundation, because there are still quite a few other frameworks that are built similarly. Core Text and Core Graphics are examples – while they don't formally belong to Core Foundation, they use the same naming and memory management conventions. There are also some APIs that are only available in Core Foundation and don't have Foundation counterparts – `CFBagRef` or `CFBitVector` (both collection types) would be examples.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is built on the c language, the CF (Core Foundation) types are C structs, and are usually wrapped in an Objective-C object (CFStringRef is wrapped by NSString, CGImageRef is wrapped by UIImage etc)

Unless you have a good reason, use the Objective-C level code. The memory management is much simpler (automatic for ARC), and in general your code will be much cleaner

Edit: as @omz pointed out, wrapped is incorrect for NSString, it is bridged, some of the other answers explain this concept

Comment: It's true that `UIImage` wraps `CGImageRef` but `NSString` is not a "wrapper" for `CFStringRef`. They're bridged, which basically means that the types are interchangeable. You can just cast a `CFStringRef` to an `NSString` (or vice-versa) and use regular `NSString` methods with it, but you cannot cast a `CGImageRef` to a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html):

> Core Foundation is a library with a set of programming interfaces conceptually derived from the Objective-C-based Foundation framework but implemented in the C language. To do this, Core Foundation implements a limited object model in C. Core Foundation defines opaque types that encapsulate data and functions, hereafter referred to as “objects.”

This is essentially sums up the difference. Core Foundation (CF) provides pure C implementations of many of the Objective-C implementations that come with the language in the form of the Foundation framework. It is correct that NS stands for 'NeXTSTEP', the name of the operating system that formed the absis for much of Mac OS X, but it also indicates that a type is an Objective C class. CF types are pure C implementations and come with C functions to manipulate them.

There are occasionally times that using the CF structures brings an advantage over the NS equivalent. For example, CFDictionary places fewer restrictions on values and keys than does NSDictionary. But unless any such problem comes up there isn't a reason for you to change your references to their CF equivalents. ARC will also not work as easily with CF types.

It is also possible to map between CF and Foundation using [toll-free bridging](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html).